# React Native Use State in Another Screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

So I have a this.state.comments in my Home Screen and that's an array. In my other screen called Comments Screen I'd like to show the results of that state. Aka id like to use that array I mean this.state.comments and display it in a FLATLIST in Comments screen. That file Comments Screen just has one function and inside it a flatlist. Any help?

Comment: just pass that array from home-screen to comments-screen, using react navigation.

Comment: first of all that screens are using react navigation ? or just parent child components, we need more info try https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: If you're not using react navigation, or want to avoid passing data between screens, you could also use AsyncStorage to set the comments object on the first screen, and retrieve it on the other - https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Home` use `this.props.navigation.navigate('Comments',{comments: this.state.comments})`

and in `Comments` screen if using react-navigation v4 use :

`const commentsArray = this.props.navigation.getParam('comments')`

if using react-navigation v5 use :

`const commentsArray = this.props.route.params.comments;`

Comment: This is exactly what I need. However I get this error doing ur const commentsArray = this.props.navigation.getParam('Comments') line.                                                     
evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate

Comment: what version of react-navigation do you use? and check for any typos.

Comment: i use v4. idk what i need to include in that small comments screen to use this line const commentsArray = this.props.navigation.getParam('comments')   i guess i need to import something to even get that to work?

Comment: please just look at this picture https://imgur.com/a/szZqbYg  THANK U!

Comment: This combined with what u wrote down didthe trick for me thank u!!

Answer (score 0):

As a response to your comment with the picture, if `Komentar` is a screen that is added in the navigation configuration you do:

```js
const Komentar = (props) =>{
 const commentsArray = props.navigation.getParam('comments');
return(
 // your code here 
)}
```

because it's a functional component you can't use `this` to access props.